# convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2\ln(n)\frac{1}{2^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2\ln(n)\frac{1}{2^n}$ converge? I tried the majorant criterium and the root test, but this doesnt help me

Comment: Yes, it does (I am almost certain, haven’t checked exact details yet). You should show what you tried! Possibly you made a mistake. You should also explain what you think about the problem

Comment: Try ratio test! Also root test should work. Show your attempt!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the ratio test, we find:

$$\lim_{\text{n}\space\to\space\infty}\left|\frac{\left(\text{n}+1\right)^2\ln\left(\text{n}+1\right)\cdot\frac{1}{2^{\text{n}+1}}}{\text{n}^2\ln\left(\text{n}\right)\cdot\frac{1}{2^\text{n}}}\right|=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\underbrace{\lim_{\text{n}\space\to\space\infty}\left|\left(1+\frac{1}{\text{n}}\right)^2\cdot\frac{\ln\left(\text{n}+1\right)}{\ln\left(\text{n}\right)}\right|}_{=\space1}=\frac{1}{2}<1\tag1$$

Answer (score 2):

Since $\ln n<n$ holds,

> $$0<\left|\frac{n^2\ln n}{2^n}\right|^{\frac1n}<\left|\frac{n^3}{2^n}\right|^{\frac1n}=\frac{(n^{\frac1n})^3}2$$

Then you know $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{\frac1n}=1$, everything is clear.